# How can I play the video in Chrome automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, video, auto

I'm going to play video on Chrome. However, the latest policy of chrome has changed. So I cannot auto play the video.
Thanks if you help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. please read [ask] and show some of your work, preferably in a [mcve] to help people to help you.

Comment: you will need your video to be muted to autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

Try muted autoplay. Later, Chrome will allow it.

```
<video ="your video url" muted autoplay>
</video>
```